# video not playing in unity when built

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, game-engine

so i have a problem of video playing on play mode but not playing when built, in the first scene i have a video playing just fine. Though the video in the first scene was attached directly to a video player, in the second scene where video is not playing, the video is assigned through a script as theres a lot of possible videos to be played depending on the buttons selected.

note that on play mode, there is no problem with the second scene unless i build it.

so i tried assigning the video from the first scene through script too, and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, are the video files not in the Resources folder?  If an asset is not linked to a scene/prefab that used it won't be included in the build.  However all assets in the Resources folder will be included.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the video is in the Resources folder or in Streaming Assets.

Answer (score 0):

this is solved! i figured i needed to have a panel component and a resources folder, which i dont have as i put my assets inside assets folder and another folders (videos, images, etc.). I didnt know it matters hehe.

Comment: Duplicate of other answers